# Entity Framework Core 1.0.1 migration looks for compiled dll instead of exe

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have an `entity framework core` class library

In the `project.json` I have added previously

```
"buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "copyToOutput": {
      "include": [ "appsettings.json" ]
    }
  },
```

as I need to run migrations on the class library so I had to adjust `project.json` to this for it to work (`1.0.0`) since ef core does not support running migrations on a class library. [Link](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5320#issuecomment-229415778)

This all worked in the past on my project but suddenly today I get the following error when I want to add a new migration

```
Add-Migration MyNewMigration
```

and I get

```
Could not find assembly '.\bin\MySolution\bin\Debug\net452\win7-x64\MyEFProject.dll'.
```

When I look at that directory it creates an `exe` instead of a `dll`, I assume because of the `"emitEntryPoint": true,` when I compile so it should not give me an error of missing dll. I had to add this as this was the [known issue](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet.html#targeting-class-library-projects-is-not-supported) to get EF migrations to work with class libraries

Only change I remember making was moving to `Entity Framework Core 1.0.1` from `1.0.0` and updating to `Visual Studio 2015 Update 3`

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
```

I set it back to `"1.0.0"` and rebuilt the project but I still get the same error

Why when it  worked before does it not anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  set the`emitEntryPoint` to `false` recompiled and it created a `dll` instead.

When running the migration afterwards I got the error
    Access to the path 'C:\Code..\ClassLibraryProject\Migrations\MyDbContextModelSnapshot.cs' is denied.

I had to give `Users` modify rights to this file to solve this.

Thereafter the commands `Add_Migrations` created the migration and the `Update-Database`updated the datbase